# how to check data member is serialized or not in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

In C# WCF which elements get serialized when we send data to an application?
When a variable has the attribute [Data member] does that variable get serialized? I don't know exactly. And how would you check to see if the data member is serialized or not? Can any one explain with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put DataContractAttribute on your class, and DataMemberAttribute on any properties you wish to have serialized.

Here is an example data contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    // This property is serialized to the client.
    [DataMember]
    public int MyField1 { get; set; }

    // This property is NOT serialized to the client.
    public string MyField2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, I believe it's still more complicated: **either** you specify all members you want to have serialized with `[DataMember]` - and in this case, really **only** those marked are really serialized. **OR:** you just don't mark anything, and in this case, all the public members are being serialized (as of .NET 3.5 SP1). You cannot mix and match - either you mark all your members you want to have serialized with the attribute - or you just don't do anything and everything public will be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

The following members are normally serialized

- any public property with both a `get` and `set` accessor
- any property marked as `DataMember`

Comment: Is there any way to confirm that data member serialized or can we get the value of serialized data?

Comment: Properties without DataMemberAttribute are not serialized by WCF.

Comment: Well, I believe it's still more complicated: **either** you specify all members you want to have serialized with `[DataMember]` - and in this case, really **only** those marked are really serialized. **OR:** you just don't mark anything, and in this case, all the public members are being serialized (as of .NET 3.5 SP1). You cannot mix and match - either you mark all your members you want to have serialized with the attribute - or you just don't do anything and everything public will be serialized.

Comment: @marc_s agree, and it's a style / convention thing - I try to *always* use `DataMember` so that its use and omission is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all public properties of your returned object are serialized but only those properties that have attribute DataMember are visible or exposed to your client application without this attribute you cannot access them from your client.

Comment: No, not really - if you start marking members with `[DataMember]` - then **only** those marked with that attribute are serialized. If you don't add any of those attributes - **then** (beginning in .NET 3.5 SP1) all public members will be serialized.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for clearing this esp. the changes beginning from .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: `DataMember` attribute has nothing to do with 'visible or exposed to client application'. That is controlled by regular accessor modifiers.